# How do I refresh recurring reminders in iOS Reminders App when they stop reminding so that they begin reminding again?

Tags: ios, ekreminder

I noticed that in iOS Reminders, when I don't respond to recurring reminders, they stop firing when they are supposed to. The count of those reminders show as red badges on the Reminders icon, and in the Reminders app, the dates show up as red.

[image]
[image]

How would I use code to cause those reminders to start firing again when they're supposed to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to get them to start reminding you on the set interval is to mark them complete, they will fast forward skipping the dates between the date they were due and now. Each time they remind you they should be marked completed, if not marked then they won't remind you again until you've completed them (unless when reminded you select the option to put it off for up to a day by long pressing/force touching on the notification.)

Unfortunately, after looking into shortcuts there is not a built in function to mark a reminder as completed and there isn't an API that will allow you to modify the reminders within iCloud.

Hopefully this solves your issue.

Comment: That's a good idea. Wouldn't marking them complete be a simple task of retrieving the reminder and setting the isComplete property to true and then saving the reminder?

Comment: The reminders show current dates in Reminders app, but they are not firing.

Comment: In my last comment, I meant that after I have done what you suggested.